# Значок для тега <li>

Tags: javascript, c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc

**Select.cshtml**

```html
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="myTabs">
        <li>@Ajax.ActionLink("1 класс", "Class1", "Work201615", new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "tabContent" }, new { @data_target = "#tabContent", @data_toggle = "tab", @class="myLi" })</li>
        <li>@Ajax.ActionLink("2 класс", "Class2", "Work201615", new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "tabContent" }, new { @data_target = "#tabContent", @data_toggle = "tab" })</li>
        <li>@Ajax.ActionLink("3 класс", "Class3", "Work201615", new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "tabContent" }, new { @data_target = "#tabContent", @data_toggle = "tab" })</li>        
    </ul>
    <div id="tabContent"></div>
```

**_Layout.cshtml**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <style>
        .myLi {
            list-style-image: url(images/check.png); /* Путь к файлу с маркером */

        }
     </stype>
      ...
```

Хочу поставить зеленый маркер перед названием первой вкладки, чтобы было так:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

но этого не происходит.

Comment: ошибку в консоли не пишет?

Comment: @teovankotm нет

Comment: не могли бы вы добавить в вопрос отрендеренный html? из браузера

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для начала, Ajax.ActionLink не поддерживает вставки в себя ничего кроме текста, так как первым аргументом у него является `class System.String` , избежать этого можно если использовать стандартные для Bootstrap библиотеки типа: GlyphIcons или FontAwesome.

тогда код вашей панели будет выглядить так:

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="myTabs">
    <li>@Ajax.ActionLink("1 класс", "Class1", "Work201615", new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "tabContent" }, new { @data_target = "#tabContent", @data_toggle = "tab", @class = "btn btn-default glyphicon glyphicon-edit" })</li>
    <li>@Ajax.ActionLink("2 класс", "Class2", "Work201615", new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "tabContent" }, new { @data_target = "#tabContent", @data_toggle = "tab" })</li>
    <li>@Ajax.ActionLink("3 класс", "Class3", "Work201615", new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "tabContent" }, new { @data_target = "#tabContent", @data_toggle = "tab" })</li>
</ul>
```

[Глифы](http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_ref_comp_glyphs.asp)

[Font-Awesome](http://fontawesome.ru/examples/)

**Ну а вот тут вполне кошерное решение:**

Основываясь на [вот этом обсуждении](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6374265/ajax-actionlink-with-image)

просто изменим класс css на

```
 .myLi
{
  background-image:url(images/check.png);
}
```

**Но если необходимо использовать кастомные изображения:**

Есть два пути :
*Хелперы*

```
    using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Web.Mvc.Ajax;

public static class ImageActionLinkHelper
{
    public static IHtmlString ImageActionLink(this AjaxHelper helper, string imageUrl, string altText, string actionName, object routeValues, AjaxOptions ajaxOptions, object htmlAttributes = null)
    {
        var builder = new TagBuilder("img");
        builder.MergeAttribute("src", imageUrl);
        builder.MergeAttribute("alt", altText);
        builder.MergeAttributes(new RouteValueDictionary(htmlAttributes));
        var link = helper.ActionLink("[replaceme]", actionName, routeValues, ajaxOptions).ToHtmlString();
        return MvcHtmlString.Create(link.Replace("[replaceme]", builder.ToString(TagRenderMode.SelfClosing)));
    }

}
```

а во вьюшке это вот так

```
 @Ajax.ImageActionLink("../../Content/Delete.png", "Delete", "Delete", new { id = item.Id }, new AjaxOptions { Confirm = "Delete contact?", HttpMethod = "Delete", UpdateTargetId = "divContactList" })
```

Нагло стырено [отсюда](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6201224/5742997)

*или*

```
<%= Ajax.ActionLink("[replacethis]", ...).Replace("[replacethis]", "<img src=\"/images/test.gif\" ... />" %>
```

Что не очень красиво, но быстро и просто. Квадратноколёсный велосипед

**UPD:** в примере неправильный закрывающий тег стиля в Layout.cshtml

Answer (score 0):

Мне кажется вы просто не там класс поставили. Нужно вот так:

```
   <ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="myTabs">
        <li class="myLi">@Ajax.ActionLink("1 класс", "Class1", "Work201615", new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "tabContent" }, new { @data_target = "#tabContent", @data_toggle = "tab" })</li>
        <li>@Ajax.ActionLink("2 класс", "Class2", "Work201615", new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "tabContent" }, new { @data_target = "#tabContent", @data_toggle = "tab" })</li>
        <li>@Ajax.ActionLink("3 класс", "Class3", "Work201615", new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "tabContent" }, new { @data_target = "#tabContent", @data_toggle = "tab" })</li>        
    </ul>
    <div id="tabContent"></div>
```

Дело в том, что хелпер `@Ajax.ActionLink` генерирует `<a>` тег. И у него нет свойства `list-style-image`. Я перенес ваш класс в `li` тег, где он и должен быть.

На всякий случай - [вот пример](https://jsfiddle.net/Teo_van_kot/ag2za8vh/).

Comment: Вы уверены что это будет работать с nav nav-tabs bootstrap?

Comment: Пример вашего варианта только c bootstrap nav http://jsfiddle.net/xFW8t/1002/

Comment: @Batanichek согласен, не сработает, я бы вообще вместо этих хитрый стилей просто в тэг а [добавил картиночку](http://jsfiddle.net/Teo_van_kot/xFW8t/1003/).

Comment: Тогда нужно будет переписывать @Ajax.ActionLink. потому что в него нельзя добавить картинку в лоб

Comment: @Batanichek нужно будет, согласен. Но мне кажется так прозрачней.

Answer (score 0):

Не много поколдовав пришел к тому что можно сделать вот [так](https://dotnetfiddle.net/weDEI2)

```
<style>
[class^="icon-w"],
[class*=" icon-w"] {
    background-image: url(http://www.mariowiki.com/images/thumb/e/e9/Check_mark.svg/50px-Check_mark.svg.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    display: inline-block;
    background-size:15px

}            
     </style>
```

Идею взял [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16362531/5018792) 
__

```
 <!-- Nav tabs -->
       <ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="myTabs">
    <li  >@Ajax.ActionLink("1 класс", "Class1", "Work201615", new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "tabContent" }, new { @data_target = "#tabContent", @data_toggle = "tab", @class = "icon-w"  })</li>
    <li>@Ajax.ActionLink("2 класс", "Class2", "Work201615", new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "tabContent" }, new { @data_target = "#tabContent", @data_toggle = "tab" })</li>
    <li>@Ajax.ActionLink("3 класс", "Class3", "Work201615", new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "tabContent" }, new { @data_target = "#tabContent", @data_toggle = "tab" })</li>        
</ul>
```